# Strange behavior of std::chrono / std::this_thread::sleep_for

Tags: c++, c++11, sleep, c++-chrono, stdthread

I have implemented the following function:

```
bool ResponsiveSleep(atomic<bool>& flag, const float nSeconds, const float grainSec=0.1f)
{
  auto tpUntil = chrono::steady_clock::now() + chrono::duration<float>(nSeconds);
  while (chrono::steady_clock::now() < tpUntil) {
    if (flag.load(memory_order::acquire)) {
      return true;
    }
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::duration<float>(grainSec));
  }
  return flag.load(memory_order::acquire);
}
```

And I'm calling it like this to sleep for 5 seconds:

```
atomic<bool> flag = false;
cout << "Start sleeping: " << double(clock()) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
TimeUtils::ResponsiveSleep(flag, 5);
cout << "Stop sleeping: " << double(clock()) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
```

However, I am getting random sleeps of 20 to 40 seconds. System: Windows 10, MSVC++ 2019 v16.5.3

Could you help to troubleshoot this? I have a guess that `chrono::duration<float>(x)` doesn't really expect number of seconds as `x`, however earlier I found examples suggesting that.

Comment: Is system too busy with other tasks?

Comment: Actually the behavior you are observing does not violate standard: it sleeps for _at least_ 5 seconds. Still _quality implementation_ should sleep not much more than asked for.
Also it works for me.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev, the system is not busy, at least the CPU load is below 10%. I saw this 2 times, then it started to sleep for ~5 seconds. Is my code correct?

Comment: Your code is fine. I recently encountered a problem with MSVC implementation of `this_thread::sleep` : https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/718 . But it is too rare to happen twice.

Comment: I recognize that might not be the gist of the question, but you could achieve pretty much the same behavior through condition variables and timed wait.

Comment: @SergeyA, better behavior, I would say. And in C++20 there's even better `std::atomic<T>::wait`, though not in MSVC yet

Comment: @AlexGuteniev I do not see a way to specify timeout for `atomic<T>::wait`?

Comment: Oh yes... The expected underlying implementations are `WaitOnAddress` on Windows or `futex` on Linux, they both take timeout, so I forgot that `atomic<T>::wait` does not accept one...
I think this would be usual extension to have timed waits for atomics, in my pull request to Microsoft STL I've added those.